# displaying output to the terminal in pexpect - Python

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm automating a installer using `pexpect`, which works nicely. However, I would like to replace the `pexpect.interact()` with some sort of `stdout`, which would allow me to keep track of the progress bar of the installer:

```
Please wait while Setup installs on your computer.

 Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 #########################################

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup has finished installing on your computer.

View readme file [Y/n]: n

[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

The source code looks like:

```
## A bunch of informations being given to the installer above
## Do you want install? y
child.sendline('y')
## now I keep tracking of the installation bar progress ... 
child.interact()
## View readme file [Y/n]: n
child.sendline('n')
```

so the last part is being done manually, become I can't get of the `child.interact()` once the install has been completed.
How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing once.  The problem is that things are working in line buffered mode by default.  Here is how I worked around it:

Right after you create your `child` (I am assuming this is a `pexpect.spawn`) you can set the attribute `child.logfile` to something - this doesn't have to be a logfile literally, it can be any file handle.  In your case, you can set it to `sys.stdout` but open this file handle in unbuffered mode.

Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect
import sys
import time
import os

def potato():
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write(str(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('bye\n')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[-1] == 'potato':
        potato()
    else:
        child = pexpect.spawn(__file__ + ' potato')
        child.logfile = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
        child.expect('bye')
```

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Comment: I quite didn't understand everything you said ... I was a little confused how could I do it

Comment: Not quite, because I have to wait until the installer is finished ... otherwise the last input will enter, and there's an error ... but the stdout part is correct

Comment: `Exception pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: ExceptionPexpect() in <bound method spawn.__del__ of <pexpect.spawn object at 0x11b6c50>> ignored`

Comment: Try changing the line `child.logfile = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` to simply `child.logfile = sys.stdout`.  Do you see the result you want?  Some things changed in python since the last time I was working with this

Comment: No, it didn't change much ... the problem is I have to wait for the installer to complete, which is what `child.interact()` does ...

Comment: Well there are other ways of doing that.  I can't say exactly how without seeing the output of your installer, but you should try using something like `child.expect('readme')` if you are waiting for the prompt to "View readme file"

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Are you able to run the example shown in my question correctly?  This is a working method for me, so if you are having some problem with it then you'll need to show how to reproduce the problem.